# How do I omit properties from angularjs form submit?

Tags: angularjs

I have a view that calls a form model from my server that includes a drop down list.

When I submit my form all of the states in my drop down list are submitted as well.  Seems silly to send back those values when the state id is all that is needed. If a form has multiple drop down lists this problem is compounded.  I also noticed that any property that is included in my from model is also submitted even if it is NOT included in my form.  That doesn't seem right at all.

**How do I omit certain properties that are not part of my form from being submitted?**

My model looks like this:

```
{
    "id":25, 
    "name":"joe smith",
    "dummyProperty": "whatever", 
    "stateId":5, 
    "states":[
        {"value":1, "label": "Alabama"}, 
        {"value:2, "label": "Alaska"}, 
        {etc...}
            ]
}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" novalidate name="form">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.id" id="id" name="id" />
    <div class="se-row">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" id="name" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="se-row">
        <label>State</state>
        <select ng-model="item.stateId" id="stateId" name="stateId">
            <option value="0">Select...</option>
            <option value="{{o.value}}" ng-repeat="o in item.states">{{o.label}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="se-row">
        <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="postNew()" ng-class="{'disabled-btn': form.$invalid}">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note:  Yes I know about ng-options but I have no use to send back the entire option object and adjust my server models to accomodate this feature.  ng-repeat works just fine.

Thanks.

**Edit**
Here is the postNew() function:

```
$scope.postNew = function () {
        ApiFactory.Crud.save({ ctrl: ApiFactory.ctrl }, $scope.item).$promise.then(function() {
            //modal stuff
        },
            function(response) {
                handleError(response);
            });
    };
```

My Factory is pretty standard:

```
TabsApp.factory('ApiFactory', function ($resource, $http, $q, $rootScope) {
    var apiService = {
        List: $resource('/api/patient/:patientId/:ctrl', { patientId: '@patientId', ctrl: '@ctrl' }),
        Crud: $resource('/api/:ctrl/:id', { ctrl: '@ctrl', id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } })
    };
//I set my url parameters here and then broadcast them down to child scopes

return apiService;
});
```

**EDIT 2**
I also tried using ngSubmit which had the identical behavior I described above.  The form still submits all the states and even the dummyProperty.

```
<form ng-submit="postNew()">
  //same as above
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of postNew()?

Comment: Have you tried `delete $scope.item.states` before `ApiFactory.Crud.save ...`?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  Makes it hard if you are reusing a controller with different models.  I understand that angular is all about the model it's just that 'normal' standards based form submission only submits what's in the form.  In this case angular's declarative mantra has an exception.

Comment: Good news that you found a way to solve your problem. I just want to warn you that I don't think the problem come from AngularJS here but from your model. The states list shouldn't be in your item, but in a standalone object of your scope. The item should only contains inputted data that must be sent to the server.

Comment: I agree in general but at some point you end up making multiple calls to the server just to fill a handful of drop downs.  This also gets more complicated if you are trying to reuse a controller with different models.  I would have to start accounting for separate objects or not have reusable controllers. I think returning all of the relevant properties of an object at once is more economical, especially for large projects with multiple forms.  Its a minor irritant that I can live with.  Thanks again.